# How often is WindowsServiceBase.Tick() called in an EWL Windows Service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-services, background-process, enterprise-web-library

I have determined that I have some intense operations that shouldn't occur in the context of a web request in my EWL web application. I see that EWL supports running a Windows Service which will be perfect for running my intense operations in the background without tying up web request threads and forcing users to wait.

I am to the point where I need to implement `void WindowsServiceBase.Tick()` but I don't see how often `Tick()` is called. How often is `Tick()` called by default and is this configurable?

I also see from the source that the Windows Service sends a "health check" email before calling `Tick()`. What's the thinking behind this? What if I don't want my email spammed with these emails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in `ServiceBaseAdapter` is cryptic, but looking very carefully you can see that `Tick` will be called ten seconds after `Init` completes and, from then on, ten seconds after the last `Tick` call completes.

The health check email will go out shortly after midnight every day. It's designed to let you know that the service is still alive.